# Group rows of data from table based on a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to achieve the below using SQL can anyone please help:

```
TOP     BOTTOM  Rocksymbol
 0        5         l
 5        10        l
10        15        ml
15        20        ml
20        25        ml
25        30        s
30        35        ml
35        40        ml
40        45        s
```

Should become:

```
TOP BOTTOM  Rocksymbol
 0    10        l
10    25        ml
25    30        s
30    40        ml
40    45        s
```

Basically wanting to group the data for same consecutive RockSymbol, where in the result the TOP of first record of the consecutive block becomes the TOP of the grouped record and the BOTTOM of last record of the consecutive block becomes the BOTTOM of the grouped record.

The number of consecutive RockSymbol records can vary.

Comment: post your efforts with question

Comment: Only consicutive Rocksymbol needs to be summed together?? because I can see ml and s and getting repeated in your desired output.

Comment: Can you also explain what you're wanting to happen here other than "Should become"? Exactly how do the top values become the bottom? If you're expecting a grouping are you expecting max values, min values, averages? Specificity please

Comment: @SagarShirke yes only consecutive Rocksymbol needs to be summed together

Comment: @ChristianBarron Basically wanting to group the consecutive Rocksymbol, where in the result the TOP of first record of the consecutive block becomes the TOP of the grouped record and the BOTTOM of last record of the consecutive block becomes the BOTTOM of the grouped record.

Comment: can one Rocksymbol appear consecutively for more than two times???

Comment: @SagarShirke Yes it can appear multiple times as well

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @ChristianBarron I am using 2012, I tried using the LAG/LEAD functions as well but couldn't come to the desired result

Comment: @DhruvJoshi both the cases will work for me update or not update, i tested your script and the only issue I see with it is I guess, it can only handle 2 consecutive occurances not more than that but in the data there can be mulitple occurances as well.

Basically wanting to group the consecutive Rocksymbol, where in the result the TOP of first record of the consecutive block becomes the TOP of the grouped record and the BOTTOM of last record of the consecutive block becomes the BOTTOM of the grouped record.

Comment: @ChristianBarron your code doesn't seem to be working for more than 2 consecutive records of thr same RockSymbol

Comment: @DhruvJoshi any update on how to do it for more than 2 consecutive occurances of the same RockSymbol

Comment: @AnkurBatra I've updated my answer and SQL Fiddle and it should work now

Comment: @ChristianBarron please try to test your script once with 3 consecutive occurances of the same RockSymbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated answer -** considering situation where we can have multiple consecutive rows with same RockSymbol.

```
SELECT
  MIN([top]) as [top],
  MAX(bottom) as bottom,
  RockSymbol
FROM
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [top]) rowid,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RockSymbol ORDER BY [top]) seqid
    ,*
  FROM
    [dbo].[tbl]
) tempt
GROUP BY
  RockSymbol,
  rowid - seqid
ORDER BY 
[top]
```

SQl fiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dc3c3/3

**Edit: Old answer** - *only for the purpose of understanding the evolution of solution*

> If you can mutate original table then probably update
>   statement
>
> ```
> UPDATE A
> SET A.[TOP]=B.[TOP]
> FROM
> [dbo].[tbl] A INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl] B ON A.[TOP]=B.BOTTOM AND A.RockSymbol=B.RockSymbol
> ```
>
> followed by removal of extra rows
>
> ```
> DELETE FROM   [dbo].[tbl] FROM [dbo].[tbl] B LEFT JOIN
> ( 
> SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Top] ORDER BY Bottom DESC) AS "Rank", [TOP], BOTTOM, RockSymbol FROM [dbo].[tbl]) A 
> ON A.[TOP]=B.[Top] AND A.[Bottom]=B.[Bottom] AND A.RockSymbol=B.RockSymbol
> WHERE A.Rank>1
> ```
>
> If you cannot update table please use a temp table or nested `SELECT`
>   query like below
>
> ```
> SELECT Q.[TOP], MAX(Q.BOTTOM) as BOTTOM,Q.RockSymbol  FROM
> (SELECT 
> ISNULL(B.[TOP],A.[TOP]) AS [TOP], 
> A.BOTTOM, 
> A.RockSymbol
> FROM
> [dbo].[tbl] A LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tbl] B ON A.[TOP]=B.BOTTOM AND A.RockSymbol=B.RockSymbol) Q
> GROUP BY Q.[TOP], Q.RockSymbol
> ```
>
> Sql fiddles link for both solution are here
>   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e1148/1/0 and
>   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e1148/7

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this to achieve what you're looking for:

```
Select [TOP], Case when Rocksymbol = lag(Rocksymbol,1,-1) over (order by [TOP]) then lag([TOP],1,-1) over (order by [TOP]) else -1 end as match into #foobar2
from #foobar 

select Min(f1.[TOP]) [TOP], Max(f1.Bottom) Bottom, f1.Rocksymbol
from #foobar f1
Left join #foobar2 f2 on f1.[TOP] = f2.match
Left join #foobar2 f3 on f1.[TOP] = f3.[TOP]
Group by Case when f2.match <> -1 then f1.[TOP] else case when f3.match <> -1 then f3.match else f3.[TOP] end end, Rocksymbol
order by [TOP]
```

SQL Fiddle of this is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b2ef2/2/0

Answer (score 0):

```
select  IDENTITY(int,1,1) as id ,* into #temp from (
select 0 as 'top', 5 as botton,'l' as rocksymble union all
select 5, 10,'l' union all
select 10, 15,'ml' union all
select 15, 20,'ml' union all
select 20, 25,'s' union all
select 25, 30,'ml' union all
select 30, 35,'s'  union all
select 35, 40,'ml' union all
select 40, 45,'ml' union all
select 45, 50,'ml'
) as  a

select a.*, b.id as bid into #temp1 from #temp a
left join #temp b
on a.[top] = b.[botton]
and a.rocksymble = b.rocksymble


select a.id,a.rocksymble,a.bid, count(case when b.bid IS null then 1 else null end) grpid into  #temp2  from #temp1 a , #temp1 b
where b.id <= a.id
group by a.id,a.rocksymble,a.bid
order by a.id

select min(b.[top]),max(b.botton),b.rocksymble from #temp2 a
join #temp1 b
on a.id = b.id
group by b.rocksymble, a.grpid
```

Comment: Could you please describe your answer as to what you have done.